# Trouble Getting (1000s of) URL HTTP codes

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I've been working on a java class that reads large quantities of URLs from a text file, opens an `HttpURLConnection` with each of them, then checks their HTTP code to see if the site connects correctly.  This functionality works fine, the problem is that I'm dealing with hundreds of thousands of links here and this method is far too slow to process all of these.  I tried using threads to make the process more efficient but for whatever reason that seemed to slow it down even further. Any suggestions for a potential solution? Thanks!

```
    public static boolean validate(String urlStr, Proxy proxy) 
{   
    boolean valid = false;  
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try
    {
        if(proxy==null)         
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(urlStr).openConnection();
        else
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(urlStr).openConnection(proxy);
        conn.setFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(7 * 1000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
        conn.connect();
        final int code = conn.getResponseCode();
        valid = (Arrays.binarySearch(errorCodes, code) == -1);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        // Ignore this for now. Eventually we should add a logger
    } finally {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Threads are not magic - they do not solve the very real problem of opening thousands of connections and performing I/O operations on that.  It may be that this is an issue with the volume of links you've opened; have you attempted to tone it down (maybe knock three or four orders of magnitude off of it) and see if that improves performance?

Comment: It's hard to know what's wrong without seeing any of your code. I wouldn't expect there to be *too* much code to post here... please edit it into the question.

Comment: why can't use java concurrent threadpool.... where u can specify the pool size.

Comment: Does it have to be java?  This kind of thing could be done quite neatly and quickly with node.js.  (I am aware that there are async HTTP libs for Java that could achieve the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing the connection management yourself, It would be better if you use Apache http client API.

[Client API tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)

and an example for multithreaded use case.

[sample code](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java%5C)

Please note that this code is only for reference, actual production code should use Pooled Executors for thread management.
Your Validate method should be part of class that implements Runnable or Callable interface depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at an asynchronous HTTP client library such as [Ning](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client).